# Operators in Python If statement

Tags: python, if-statement, operators

This is a simple snippet of code that I have:

```
>>> test = ['asas', 'asa12', 'sdsdsd12', 'vccvcvcv', 'rertrtt11']
>>> for i in test:
...     if '11' in i:
...         print i
...
rertrtt11
```

Works as expected.Now to catch elements containing either 11 or 12,I do this :

```
>>> test = ['asas', 'asa12', 'sdsdsd12', 'vccvcvcv', 'rertrtt11']
>>> for i in test:
...     if '11' or '12' in i:
...         print i
...
asas
asa12
sdsdsd12
vccvcvcv
rertrtt11
```

That was unexpected.I was hoping to catch only the elements with 11 or 12 in it but the output contained all the elements.

While trying to troubleshoot,I tried an **and** operator to try to understand the behaviour:

```
>>> test = ['asas', 'asa12', 'sdsdsd12', 'vccvcvcv', 'rertrtt11']
>>> for i in test:
...     if '11' and '12' in i:
...         print i
...
asa12
sdsdsd12
```

Now I am thoroughly confused as I was expecting an empty set since there are no elements with both 11 and 12 in them.Is my understanding of operator functioning in python completely wrong ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'11' or '12' in i` is evaluated like this

```
('11') or ('12' in i)
```

So, the first part is always truthy. That is why all of them are printed. In the second case,

```
('11') and ('12' in i)
```

Here, first part is always Truthy, so it prints only the items which contain `12`. You might want do

```
if '11' in i and '12' in i:
```

or

```
if all(item in i for item in ('11', '12')):
```

To have or condition, you can use `any` function, like this

```
if any(item in i for item in ('11', '12')):
```

Answer (score 1):

To give you a small and easy fix , you should try :

```
if (('11' in i) or ('12' in i)):
    #do something
```

or

```
if (('11' in  i) and ('12' in i)):
    #do another thing
```

This is not an unexpected error , Kindly refer to docs

Answer (score 1):

The `or` and `and` operators do not chain the way you think they do.

```
if '11' and '12' in i: #this problem is the same for or
```

First python will perform `'12' in i` as `in` has a higher precedence than `and`. It will then `and` the return from the `in` test with `'12'`, which is implicitly convertible to `True`.

To get the effect you actually want, you'd need to do:

```
if '11' in i and '12' in i: # same for or
```

This will properly check if `'11'` is in `i`, then if `'12'` is in `i`, then `and`/`or` the results of those two tests together.